# Identify all local extrema of a fitted smoothing spline via R function 'smooth.spline'

Tags: r, spline, smoothing

I have a 2-dimensional data set.

I use the R's `smooth.spline` function to smooth my points graph following an example in this article:

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/predict.smooth.spline.html

So that I get the spline graph similar to the green line on this picture

[image]

I'd like to know the `X` values, where the first derivative of the smoothing spline equals zero (to determine exact minimum or maximum).

My problem is that my initial dataset (or a dataset that I could auto-generate) to feed into the `predict()` function does not contain such exact `X` values that correspond to the smoothing spline extrema.

How can I find such `X` values?

Here is the picture of the first derivative of the green spline line above

[image]

But exact X coordinate of extremums are still not exact.

My approximate R script to generate the pictures looks like the following

```
sp1 <- smooth.spline(df)

pred.prime <- predict(sp1, deriv=1)
pred.second <- predict(sp1, deriv=2)

d1 <- data.frame(pred.prime)
d2 <- data.frame(pred.second)

dfMinimums <- d1[abs(d1$y) < 1e-4, c('x','y')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there are two problems here.

1. You are using the original x-values and they are spaced too far apart AND
2. Because of the wide spacing of the x's, your threshold for where you consider the derivative "close enough" to zero is too high.

Here is basically your code but with many more x values and requiring smaller derivatives. Since you do not provide any data, I made a coarse approximation to it that should suffice for illustration.

```
## Coarse approximation of your data
x = runif(300, 0,45000)
y = sin(x/5000) + sin(x/950)/4 + rnorm(300, 0,0.05) 
df = data.frame(x,y)
sp1 <- smooth.spline(df)
```

### Spline code

```
Sx = seq(0,45000,10)
pred.spline <- predict(sp1, Sx)
d0 <- data.frame(pred.spline)
pred.prime <- predict(sp1, Sx, deriv=1)
d1 <- data.frame(pred.prime)

Mins = which(abs(d1$y) < mean(abs(d1$y))/150)

plot(df, pch=20, col="navy")
lines(sp1, col="darkgreen")
points(d0[Mins,], pch=20, col="red")
```

[image: Extrema]

The extrema look pretty good.

```
plot(d1, type="l")
points(d1[Mins,], pch=20, col="red")
```

[image: Derivative]

The points identified look like zeros of the derivative.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. As I understand, your approach is to generate sufficiently dense samples of X to come closer to the extrema.

Comment: Yes,  That is the most important part.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my R package `SplinesUtils`: https://github.com/ZheyuanLi/SplinesUtils, which can be installed by

```
devtools::install_github("ZheyuanLi/SplinesUtils")
```

The function to be used are `SmoothSplinesAsPiecePoly` and `solve`. I will just use the example under the documentation.

```
library(SplinesUtils)

## a toy dataset
set.seed(0)
x <- 1:100 + runif(100, -0.1, 0.1)
y <- poly(x, 9) %*% rnorm(9)
y <- y + rnorm(length(y), 0, 0.2 * sd(y))

## fit a smoothing spline
sm <- smooth.spline(x, y)

## coerce "smooth.spline" object to "PiecePoly" object
oo <- SmoothSplineAsPiecePoly(sm)

## plot the spline
plot(oo)

## find all stationary / saddle points
xs <- solve(oo, deriv = 1)
#[1]  3.791103 15.957159 21.918534 23.034192 25.958486 39.799999 58.627431
#[8] 74.583000 87.049227 96.544430

## predict the "PiecePoly" at stationary / saddle points
ys <- predict(oo, xs)
#[1] -0.92224176  0.38751847  0.09951236  0.10764884  0.05960727  0.52068566
#[7] -0.51029209  0.15989592 -0.36464409  0.63471723
points(xs, ys, pch = 19)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One caveat in the @G5W implementation that I found is that it sometimes returns *multiple* records close around extrema instead of a single one. On the diagram they cannot be seen, since they all fall into one point effectively.

The following snippet from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48955848/r-how-to-aggregate-by-real-values-column-with-given-error-tolerance) filters out single extrema points with the minimum value of the first derivative:

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 <- df  %>%
  group_by(round(y, 4)) %>% 
  filter(abs(d1) == min(abs(d1))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-5)
```