# R: how to aggregate by real values column with given error tolerance

Tags: r, group-by, aggregate

Assuming I have a data frame:

```
t <- data.frame(d1=c( 694, 695, 696, 2243, 2244, 2651, 2652 ),
                d2=c(1.80950881, 1.80951007, 1.80951052, 1.46499982, 1.46500087, 1.14381419, 1.14381319 ))

    d1       d2
1  694 1.809509
2  695 1.809510
3  696 1.809511
4 2243 1.465000
5 2244 1.465001
6 2651 1.143814
7 2652 1.143813
```

I'd like to group by the column `d2` real values that have very close but not exactly equal values. Thus, in this example, after aggregation, I'd like to obtain the following data set:

```
    d1       d2
1  694 1.809509
2 2243 1.465000
3 2652 1.143813
```

taking the row with minimum `d2` value from each group.

Using the `aggregate` function, my first attempt:

```
aggregate(t, by=list(t$d2), FUN=min)
   Group.1   d1       d2
1 1.143813 2652 1.143813
2 1.143814 2651 1.143814
3 1.465000 2243 1.465000
4 1.465001 2244 1.465001
5 1.809509  694 1.809509
6 1.809510  695 1.809510
7 1.809511  696 1.809511
```

is far from reaching my goal.

How can I tell `aggregate` to group not by exact equality, but by equality with provided error tolerance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach with tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
t %>%
  group_by(round(d2, 1)) %>% #group by rounded d2
  filter(d2 == min(d2)) %>% #filter min d1 in each group
  ungroup() %>% #ungroup so you can remove the grouping column
  select(-3)
```

Comment: This one produces exact result as I expect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This work with your toy data i don't know with real one, you might have to round to more or less digits

```
aggregate(t, by=list(round(t$d2,4)), FUN=min)
```

Comment: Great! That's almost what I need. The only caveat is that instead of the "the row with minimum d2 value from each group" I get all minimum values from all columns, so that the result set contains d1 from one initial row and d2 from another.

Comment: soy you want to get the minimum value from d2 and the corresponding d1 value?

Comment: The example in the question hopefully illustrates my goal well.
Your suggestion produces very close result but the third row is
2651 1.143813 instead of my expected 2652 1.143813

Comment: I see, i think the other answer gets exactly what you want, i don't know how to exactly what you want with aggregate function

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion though. I like its minimalism and will think whether I can actually use it as is.